# Must NZ citizens enter NZ with their NZ passports?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, new-zealand

Suppose someone is a dual citizen, with two passports: NZ and somewhere else.

Must this person enter NZ on their NZ passport?

(This is the case for US passport holders - when entering to the US - to my understanding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not required for a New Zealand citizen to enter using a New Zealand passport.  [1] However, if the person intends to stay longer than what would normally be allowed by a tourist of the nationality of their passport, they would have to prove their NZ citizenship in some way.

For example, a dual Mexican/NZ citizen who only holds a valid Mexican passport, would be allowed to enter New Zealand for up to 3 months under visitor visa rules.

1. [A2.35 New Zealand citizens](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/opsmanual/#35031.htm) from the New Zealand Immigration Operational Manual